# Insertar una hoja de google sheet en una página

Tags: html, excel, web

Hola qué tal? quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para insertar una hoja de cálculo en mi página web, he podido lograr ponerlo desde la opción "publicar en web" pero no sé cómo hacer que se actualice por sí solo cuando surjan cambios en la hoja de cálculo, alguien podría darme una mano?
edit: leí por ahí que se necesita el "libro de excel" para que se actualice en mi página pero la verdad que no entiendo a qué se refiere

Answer (score 2):

Hace tiempo hice lo mismo que tú en Google Drive y los cambios de la hoja se hacían automáticamente.

Sigue estos pasos:

1. Sube tu hoja Excel a Google Drive.
2. Cuando se haya cargado, dale doble clic para abrirla.
3. En la parte superior, elige la opción *Abrir con hojas de cálculo Google*.
4. Se abrirá en otra ventana, en la parte superior dale clic en *Archivo* y selecciona la opción *Publicar en la web*.
5. En la ventana que se abre, seleccionar *Vincular todo el documento*, selecciona *Página web*.
6. En la parte inferior de la ventana hay una opción que dice *Contenido publicado*, pícale ahí selecciona *Todo el documento*.
7. La parte clave viene aquí: encasilla la opción *Volver a publicar automáticamente...*
8. Al final, dale clic en donde dice *Incorporar* y te darán el código para poderlo pegar en tu página web.

Con estos pasos podrás hacer cambios en tiempo real a tu documento desde tu página web.

Espero haberte ayudado.